# How can I parse words when there is only Enter Mark between them in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an interesting data, Country names side by side, I need to get each one of them for spesific id.
I just don't know how can I parse those country names.

[image]

When I try to locate that mark,

```
select locate('¶',facility_country) from table_name,
```

it only returns me 0, doesn't work. I need to find a way to parse country names from that string.

for each id, I want to multiply my data on countries. Or maybe make a new dim table out of them: id and countries. In order to type my parse code or function, still not sure how to do it though but I can manage, I just need to locate that mark so I can separate.

I tried using Ascii, such like:

```
select CHAR(182);
```

This returns me the same mark.

```
select locate(CHAR(182),facility_country) from table_name;
```

When I try like that still I can't locate the mark, it only returns me 0.

How can I parse those county names with that Enter Mark? I have done similar things with "," or " " but first time I see something like that.

Edit: When I copy full text it looks like this after I paste:

USA
Australia
Brazil
Canada
France
Germany
Ireland
Israel
Italy
Netherlands
New Zealand
Switzerland
United Kingdom

(stackoverflow puts them side by side like that, on dbeaver this is what I see: )[image]

edit2: @RiggsFolly requested this:

```
SELECT facility_country from clinical_trials LIMIT 5
```

output:

[image]

There are many lines like the line3.

edit3: @Tangentially Perpendicular solved it. We are looking at rendered image so we don't know what is the raw data, Apperantly its Char(10) and I can locate with it.

Comment: its rarely a good idea to put `something` delimited strings in a column

Comment: If LOCATE is returning `0` then the char on the database is not the one you are using in the LOCATE function

Comment: So post one full value as TEXT on the question and someone will probably tell you which actual character that is

Comment: FWIW, I don't answer questions with 'wanna' in them.

Comment: Don’t understand what this should be good for at all? First of all I would never identify a country by a numeric Id but always use the isoAlpha code for it. Second, there are many possibilities to fetch country names and alpha codes from the internet and put them in your du table. So why use this shitty file you have?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Those are different clinical trials and the countries involved, instead of all countries involved in 1 row, I want to multiply them so if I group by them by a spesific country for a lot of trials, I Can see how many records etc.

Comment: @RiggsFolly When I post Full value on text it seems like;

USA
Canada
Italy

I will add this. If its not that mark, I don't know what it is.

Comment: That symbol is called a `pilcrow` or paragraph mark. Its ASCII value is 244. Assuming nothing odd is going on when it's rendered, you should be able to split on `char(244)`

Comment: They look like Newline characters, but not sure if they are unix or windows line endings? You didnt paste a simple unadulterated line from that file with odd chars in it??

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Sorry, When I try char(244) this is what it returns: ô. char(182) returns this: ¶. Both of them doesn't return anything with locate though.

Comment: @RiggsFolly someone else scrapped that data, I don't really get what you are talking about.

Comment: That data is in a column on your database .. RIGHT? If so, do a `SELECT facility_country LIMIT 5;` and then copy and paste those 5 result rows into your question

Comment: The trouble is that we're looking at an image of rendered data. There's no way to tell what the original data is. My guess would be `char(13)` or `char(10)` but without raw data it's impossible to tell. I doubt posting raw data here will help with that - it'll just get interpreted

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular THANK YOU! I got your point very well and IT WORKS. Char(10) Works. I can locate it now so I can parse like any other string with operators like substring_index, locate etc.

Comment: Glad to be of help 